# Strange FPS drop

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl, gpu

I have written [this small three.js scene](http://jsfiddle.net/b5L4hheL/) with 360,000 vertices in 3 buffer geometries and have added a `stats` FPS counter to check their evolution.

I experience a weird behaviour on my middle-range laptop : 60 FPS with a 'high' zoom, 60 FPS with a 'low' zoom, but 30-40 on a 'middle' zoom (where the meshes'corners are over the camera's frustum, plus or minus one order of magnitude). Always.

[image]

This behaviour makes no sense to me. How can it be explained ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informed guess here. Let's call your images, left to right, A, B, and C.

In A, many lines are outside the view frustum, and are simply not drawn.

In B, all lines are drawn.

In C, all lines are drawn but not many pixels are filled. Also, there are few spaces that have not been flled in by at least one line, so if Z-buffering is on, many pixels will simply never get re-filled.

So in summary:

A benefits (+) from frustum culling, but probably has low Z complexity (-), and doesn't fill as many pixels as B (+).

B benefits little or none from frustum culling (-), and only from Z buffering (if any) in the center densest areas (small+). More pixels appear to be filled than in A (-).

C gets no frustum benefit (-) but fills fewer pixels (+) and gets the best Z-buffering benefit (if any) (+).